# Adaptive chained payment additional info with ipn url

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, payment, paypal-adaptive-payments

I have read several postings here regarding IPN and chained payments and I am having a difficult time understanding it since this is all new to me. But my scenario is simple and here is what I am trying to achieve.

buyer pays seller(seller) seller pay me commission. That all works. But I need validation for back end work.

I specify my ipn listener with the variable

```
$ipnurl = "http://example.com/ipnlistener.php?adid=$adid
```

Because adid is my key to everything in the backend.

In my API I use NVP and define the call like this. Keep in mind it all works except the IPN stuff.

```
$request_parameters = array (
   "actionType" => "PAY",
   "ipnNotificationUrl" => "$ipnurl",
   "clientDetails.applicationID" => "$ppappid",
   "clientDetails.ipAddress" => "127.0.0.1",
   "feesPayer" => "PRIMARYRECEIVER",
   "memo" => "$adtitle",
   "receiverList.receiver(0).amount" => "$r1amount",
   "receiverList.receiver(0).email" => "$r1email",
   "receiverList.receiver(0).primary" => "true",
   "receiverList.receiver(1).amount" => "$r2amount",
   "receiverList.receiver(1).email" => "$r2email",
   "receiverList.receiver(1).primary" => "false",
   "requestEnvelope.errorLanguage" => "en_US",
   "requestEnvelope.detailLevel" => "ReturnAll",
   "currencyCode" => "USD",
   "returnUrl" => $adpage,
   "cancelUrl" => $adpage
);
```

for simple test purpose, I have the following as part of my ipnlistener so I can see what comes in.

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)  {
        if($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1){
                $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
        } else {
                $value = urlencode($value);
        }
        $req .= "&$key=$value";
}

$result = print_r($_POST, true);
file_put_contents('/tmp/ipnlistener.txt', $result);
```

With the above scnario, the log filecontains the following:

```
Array
(
    [transaction] => Array
        (
            [0] => NONE
            [1] => Completed
        )

    [log_default_shipping_address_in_transaction] => false
    [action_type] => PAY
    [ipn_notification_url] => http://www.example.com/ipnlistener.php
    [charset] => windows-1252
    [transaction_type] => Adaptive Payment PAY
    [notify_version] => UNVERSIONED
    [cancel_url] => http://www.example.com/showad.php?adid=20
    [verify_sign] => ********
    [sender_email] => ******
    [fees_payer] => PRIMARYRECEIVER
    [return_url] => http://www.example.com/showad.php?adid=20
    [memo] => Leica M Lens CLOSE UP to Sony NEX
    [reverse_all_parallel_payments_on_error] => false
    [pay_key] => *******
    [status] => COMPLETED
    [payment_request_date] => Tue Oct 14 11:10:18 PDT 2014
)
```

As you can see, it appears like its an app specific IPN.  I need the real data to complete transaction.

If I remove the ipnurl and tune ipn notifications back on on the site, i get what I expect BUT WITHOUT the adid I so deperately need.

It looks like this

```
Array
(
    [transaction_subject] =>
    [payment_date] => 07:40:38 Oct 14, 2014 PDT
    [txn_type] => web_accept
    [last_name] => ***
    [residence_country] => US
    [item_name] =>
    [payment_gross] => 0.03
    [mc_currency] => USD
    [business] => ***
    [payment_type] => instant
    [protection_eligibility] => Ineligible
    [verify_sign] => ***
    [payer_status] => unverified
    [tax] => 0.00
    [payer_email] => ***
    [txn_id] => ***
    [quantity] => 0
    [receiver_email] => ***
    [first_name] => Jorge
    [payer_id] => ***
    [receiver_id] => ***
    [memo] => Leica M Lens CLOSE UP to Sony NEX
    [item_number] =>
    [payer_business_name] => ZeissImages
    [payment_status] => Completed
    [payment_fee] => 0.03
    [mc_fee] => 0.03
    [mc_gross] => 0.03
    [custom] =>
    [charset] => windows-1252
    [notify_version] => 3.8
    [ipn_track_id] => ***
)
```

The question is how can I get the transaction IPN with my added cutom parameter?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Save a record in your local database that has the data you need along with the PayKey of the transaction you're making.  Then when the app specific IPN hits you can pull that data back out of your database using that PayKey.